# DISTINCT values with ", " divider in GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: android, sqlite, distinct, group-concat, divider

```
GROUP_CONCAT(g_value,", ")
```

This gives me all values with [comma]+[space] divider

> apple, orange, banana, apple, apple

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g_value)
```

This gives me only distinct values with "," divider without space.

> apple,orange,banana

How to get DISTINCT values with ", " divider?

> apple, orange, banana

Comment: I'm not familiar with that function but have you tried GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g_value, ", ")?

Comment: He tried, and got an error message. Not mentioning this in the question is very inconsiderate.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is

```
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT g_value SEPARATOR ', ')
```